# R: apply a function to every element of two variables respectively

Tags: r, apply, mapply, multiple-arguments

I have a function with two variables x and y:

```
fun1 <- function(x,y) {
  z <- x+y
  return(z)
}
```

The function work fine by itself:

```
fun1(15,20)
```

But when I try to use it with two vectors for x and y with an apply function I do not get the correct 56*121 array

```
Lx  <- c(1:56)
Ly <- c(1:121)

mapply(fun1, Lx, Ly)
```

I would be grateful for your help and also on advice on the fastest solution (eg is a data.table or dplyr solution faster than apply).

Comment: think you want `outer` : `outer(Lx, Ly, fun1)` or [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858734/sum-of-subvectors-of-a-vector-in-r)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use `mapply()` you have to provide it with n lists of arguments that have same size, and that will be passed to the function n by n, as in:

```
mapply(fun1,c(1,2,3), c(4, 5, 6))
[1] 5 7 9
```

or one argument can be a scalar as in:

```
mapply(fun1,c(1,2,3), 4)
[1] 5 6 7
```

Since you're trying to use all combinations of `Lx` and `Ly`, you can iterate one list, then iterate the other, like:

```
sapply(Lx, function(x) mapply(fun1,x,Ly))
```

or

```
sapply(Ly, function(y) mapply(fun1,Lx,y))
```

which produces same result as [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr)'s proposition in their comment above

```
outer(Lx, Ly, fun1)
```

where `outer()` is much quicker

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` for this problem, as you've described it, is weird.  You seem to want to work with vectors, not data.frames, and `dplyr` functions expect data.frames in and return data.frames out, i.e. it's inputs and outputs are idempotent.  For working with vectors, you should use `outer`.  But `dplyr` *could* be shoehorned into doing this task...

```
# define variables
Lx  <- c(1:56)
Ly <- c(1:121)
dx <- as.data.frame(Lx)
dy <- as.data.frame(Ly)

require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)  # for the %<>% operator

# the dplyr solution
(dx %<>% mutate(dummy_col = 1)) %>% 
     full_join(
         (dy %<>% mutate(dummy_col = 1)), by='dummy_col') %>% 
     select(-dummy_col) %>% 
     transmute(result = Lx + Ly)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're using vectors of different length but maybe this will help if I understand correctly. I just made a dumby function with variable i

```
fun1 <- function(x,y) {
  z <- x+y
  return(z)
}


fun1(15,20)


Lx  <- c(1:56)
Ly <- c(1:121)


fun1I <- function(x,y,i)
{


  fun1(x[i],y[i])


}


fun1IR <- function(x,y)
{


  function(i)fun1I(x=x,y=y,i=i) #return dumby function

}



testfun <- fun1IR(Lx,Ly) # creates function with data Lx and Ly in variable i

mapply(testfun, 1:min(length(Lx),length(Ly)))
```