# Object not found - nested function - R

Tags: r, environment-variables, nested-function

I am still getting used with functions. I had a look in environments documentation but I can't figure out how to solve the error. Lets see what I tried until now:

I have a list of documents. Lets suppose it is "core"

```
library(dplyr)
table_1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
table_2 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

core <- list(table_1, table_2)
```

Then, I have to run the function `documents_` for each element of the list. This function gives some parameters to execute in another nested function:

```
documents_ <- function(i) {

  core_processed <- as.data.frame(core[[i]])

  x <- 1:nrow(core_processed)
  y <- 1:ncol(core_processed)

  temp <- sapply(x, function(x) mapply(calc_dens_,x,y))

  return(temp)

}
```

Inside that, there is the function `calc_dens`, which is:

```
calc_dens_ <- function(x, y) {

  core_temp <- core_processed %>%
    filter(X2 == x & X3 == y)

   return(core_temp)
}
```

Then, for iterate for each element of the list, I tried without success:

```
calc <- lapply(c(1:2), function(i) documents_(i))

Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'core_processed' not found
```

The `calc_dens` function doesn't get the results of the `documents_` (environment problem. Is there a way to solve this, or another better approach? My function is more complex than this, but the main elements are in this example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should include the packages that you used. (`dplyr`?). Also, if I put `calc_dens_` inside `documents_`, it runs fine in my machine.

Comment: You should pass `core_processed` to `calc_dens` explicitly. The function doesn't appear to have access to the variable through the environments available to it.

Comment: `core_processed` is not a global variable, its scope is limited to only within `documents_` function.  See the comment above for a solution.

Comment: You are all correct. Putting the complete function calc_dens_  inside documents_ worked well.

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters have said, the problem is that you are referring to a variable, `core_processed` that is not in scope. You can make it a global variable, but it might be more sensible just to use it in a closure like this:

```
table_1 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
table_2 <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
cores <- list(table_1, table_2)

documents_ <- function(core_processed) {
    x <- 1:nrow(core_processed)
    y <- 1:ncol(core_processed)
    calc_dens <- function(x, y) core_processed %>% filter(X2 == x & X3 == y)
    sapply(x, function(x) mapply(calc_dens, x, y))
}

calc <- lapply(cores, documents_)
```

If `cores` is a list of data frames, you do not need to to use `as.data.frame` and since you use `lapply`, there is no need to apply over indices and then index into the list. So the code I wrote here is simplified but does the same as your code.

I have to wonder, though, is this really what you want? The `sapply` over `x` and then `mapply` over `x` and `y` -- where `x` is the one from the `sapply` and not the ist you built in `documents_` -- looks mighty strange to me.

Comment: That is. The context is the following: The table is a edge list of a network. Each x is the value of affiliation. Each Y is value of a specific year. In the case, I want to filter for each cluster (x), a network measure for each year(y). For example, for the cluster 1, I will calculate the transitivity in each year between 2009:2017, and continues for each cluster inside x.

Comment: If you want all combinations of `x` and `y`, then `expand.grid(x, y)` might be a better approach. The `mapply` inside the `sapply` is not doing that.

Comment: Good observation. The code was wrong. Following what is stated here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352647/r-apply-on-a-function-with-two-variables), I changed `x` to `Lx <- 1:nrow(core_processed)` and `y` as well. After, the code was changed to `sapply(Lx, function(x) mapply(calc_dens,x,Ly))`