# Grouping the subvectors of a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to program a fast function that takes as input a vector `v`, and two positions `left` and `right`. Then the function should return the sum of all subvectors of `v` that contain both `left` and `right`.

For example, if `v = c(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)` and `left = 2`, `right = 4`, then the subvectors that contain both `v_2` and `v_4` are:

```
c(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)
c(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)
c(v_2, v_3, v_4)
c(v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)
```

In particular, `v_2, v_3, v_4` are always contained by these sets. Finally, I want a function that gives

```
S(v, 2, 4) = c(sum(v[1:4]), sum(v[1:5]), sum(v[2:4]), sum(v[2:5]))
```

My current solution is to make `v` into an upper triangular matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
v <- rnorm(1:5)
vmat <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
for(i in 1:nrow(vmat)) for(j in i:nrow(vmat)) vmat[i,j] <- sum(v[i:j])
```

There are also more efficient ways to create this matrix that are compared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858734/sum-of-subvectors-of-a-vector-in-r).

And then

```
Smat <-function(vmat, left, right) vmat[1:left, right:nrow(vmat)]
```

gives the correct sums.

Since this operation has to happen a lot of times for different `v` vectors, I am interested if I can program this in a more intelligent way. I feel that the current implementation is sub-optimal because I need to allocate a matrix for every vector, from which I only use the upper triangle.

Comment: Not very clear to me. ... I don't get *For example, if v = c(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5) and left = 2, right = 4, then I need to get sum(v[1:4]),  sum(v[1:5]), sum(v[2:4]), sum(v[2:5])*

Comment: updated the post so that it is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
subvector_sum <- function(v, start, end){
  v_list <- c(
    lapply(1:start,
           FUN = function(i, end) i:end,
           end),
    lapply(end:length(v),
           FUN = function(i, start) start:i,
           start)
  )

  v_list <- c(unique(v_list), list(seq_along(v)))

  vapply(v_list, function(index) sum(v[index]), numeric(1))
}

set.seed(1)
v <- rnorm(5)
subvector_sum(v, 2, 4)
```

For comparison, here are benchmarks of the two approaches when run on vectors of length 5, 100, and 1000.

```
library(microbenchmark)

subvector_matrix <- function(v, left, right){
  vmat <- matrix(0, length(v), length(v))
  for(i in 1:nrow(vmat)) for(j in i:nrow(vmat)) vmat[i,j] <- sum(v[i:j])
  vmat[1:left, right:nrow(vmat)]
}

set.seed(1)
v5 <- rnorm(5)
v100 <- rnorm(100)
v1000 <- rnorm(1000)

microbenchmark(
  apply5 = subvector_sum(v5, 2, 4),
  matrix5 = subvector_matrix(v5, 2, 4),
  apply100 = subvector_sum(v100, 2, 4),
  matrix100 = subvector_matrix(v100, 2, 4),
  apply1000 = subvector_sum(v1000, 2, 4)
)

Unit: microseconds
      expr       min         lq        mean    median         uq       max neval
    apply5    21.700    26.5390    43.54169    30.938    60.2630    84.456   100
   matrix5    29.618    38.1225    47.03129    46.480    55.1310    73.312   100
  apply100   229.026   255.1260   274.39212   273.600   292.5145   351.018   100
 matrix100 10273.639 10596.3570 11894.37717 10850.604 13593.2015 15193.747   100
 apply1000  5371.710  5520.0945  6305.76903  5663.346  5886.3600 13557.719   100
```

As you can see, the `apply` approach I've suggested runs faster on a vector of length 1000 than your matrix approach on a vector of length 100.  I didn't want to wait to see how long it would take to do the matrix on a vector of length 1000, so it is omitted here.